# How to include “matlabengine.hpp” and “MatlabDataArray.hpp” files in C++ Ubuntu's includepath

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, include

I use Visual Studio Code and I also tried using ATOM and I get the same problem where the compiler can't find the path to some file.
In a .cpp file i have icluded the following
`#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp" #include "MatlabEngine.hpp"`

And I get the following error:

```
fatal error: MatlabDataArray.hpp: No such file or directory
```

the path of the files is `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include/` and I have tried to put it in the `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "../../../../usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include",
            "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include/**",
            "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/cpp",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

But I get the same error.
If I try to put the path in the initial `#include "path/MatlabDataArray.hpp"` i don't get the error, but inside the `"MatlabEngine.hpp"`file there are more #include for which it can't find
the file path either.

Example if I try `#include "../../../../usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include/MatlabDataArray.hpp" #include "../../../../usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include/MatlabEngine.hpp"`
I get:

```
In file included from /home/dani/Escritorio/mcc/file1.cpp:6:
/home/dani/Escritorio/mcc/../../../../usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/extern/include/MatlabEngine.hpp:6:10: fatal error: MatlabDataArray/TypedArray.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <MatlabDataArray/TypedArray.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: What is `c_cpp_properties.json`? What build system do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn’t use such a file. Also it is a Windows program and doesn’t run on Linux. Please [edit] your question with relevant information regarding how you build your program.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you’re using Visual Studio Code, which is an entirely different tool. I haven’t used it, but the docs suggest that the JSON file you created is for IntelliSense, and you need a `tasks.json` file to describe the build process. Please read the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: Thanks I will try that